# Client encoding for MySQL is wrong only in some PHP files?

Tags: mysql, encoding, error-handling

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: 
[2002] �Ώۂ̃R���s���[�^�ɂ����ċ��ۂ��ꂽ���߁A�ڑ��ł��܂����ł����B 
(trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in \includes\connect_to_mysql.php
on line 16
```

[Here's a permanent link to the connect script: http://pastebin.com/zudvxuZX](http://pastebin.com/zudvxuZX).

As you can see, there are strange characters being output.  I changed the encoding to be `UTF-8`, and I also tried `ISO-2022-JP` because my OS language is Japanese.  The error message looked the same.

Well, **I use this same connect script on another page**.  It's exactly the same, and it works.  So, I'm thinking to myself: *Why would it fail when referenced in one php file and not fail when referenced in another?*

Is there another place where I can view this error?  Or does anybody know how I can see the full error where it's being output now, without these unusual characters?  Or, could someone tell me why a connect script may fail in one location and not another?  Here are the locations:

Working: `csite/includes/connect_to_mysql.php`
Not working: `dsite/includes/connect_to_mysql.php`

I'm also **referencing the connect_to_mysql.php script via the same file** in a different location:

Working: `csite/js/ajaxvalidate.js`
Not working: `dsite/js/ajaxvalidate.js`

I'm **using a different index.php file**, though:

Working: `csite/index.php`
Not working: `dsite/index.php`

I am also **connecting to the same database** with both index files.

Working: `$db_name = "ddata";`
Not working: `$db_name = "ddata";`

Comment: Is the encoding being set explicitly/differently? I believe it is a "global" setting. Look for `mysql_set_charset` or "SET NAMES", perhaps? I think it can be viewed with `mysql_client_encoding`, but I don't even use PHP :-)

Comment: I didn't set the mysql charset.  I used this line of code, only: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`.  I do remember setting the charset to utf-8 when I created the DB, though.

Comment: Are the two php scripts in the same directory? Are they sent to your browser with the same content encoding (check the headers sent with your page)? If you fiddle with your browser's encoding, can you read it? If the server sets the charset, then the meta tag is usually ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

From [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html),

> The error (**2002**) Can't connect to ... normally means that there is no
>   MySQL server running on the system or that you are using an incorrect
>   Unix socket file name or TCP/IP port number when trying to connect to
>   the server. You should also check that the TCP/IP port you are using
>   has not been blocked by a firewall or port blocking service.

Comment: And the solution works.  I'll accept when the site allows me.  Thank you, sir.